# Why is my macro not expanded inside of \special{...}?

Tags: macros, expansion

I am writing my first LaTeX/TeX macro and not going anywhere with it. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong in the code below.

I have the following definitions.

```
\def\defcolor#1#2{%
   \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}

\def\colortext#1#2{%
   \special{ts: text fillcolor \csname#1\endcsname}{#2}%
}
```

I use them in my LaTeX file as follows:

```
\defcolor{red}{1.0,0.0,0.0}
```

Now when I use `\red` I see 1.0,0.0,0.0 in the text. Which is what I am expecting and happy to see! The problem is the `\colortext` command. When I call the `\colortext` command like the following

```
\colortext{red}{sometext}
```

I see the following output in my .dvi file

```
ts: text fillcolor \red
```

Instead of what I want

```
ts: text fillcolor 1.0,0.0,0.0
```

The `\red` macro is not getting expanded inside the replacement text of the `\colortext` macro.
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not familar with the specials. But it works fine for me---I get `ts: text fillcolor 1.0,0.0,0.0` in dvi file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make sure that `\red` is defined before you use `\colortext`, because `\csname UndefinedMacro\endcsname` will expand only so far till `\UndefinedMacro`, not further.

You could add a test for this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\colortext#1#2{%
   \@ifundefined{#1}
      {\PackageError{yourpackage}{Color '#1' not defined yet!}{}}
      {\special{ts: text fillcolor \csname#1\endcsname}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother
```

If this isn't the problem expand it manually:

```
\makeatletter
\def\colortext#1#2{%
   \@ifundefined{#1}
      {\PackageError{yourpackage}{Color '#1' not defined yet!}{}}
      {{\edef\@tempa{\noexpand\special{ts: text fillcolor \csname#1\endcsname}}\@tempa{#2}}%
}
\makeatother
```

You can then debug it by adding `\show\@tempa` after its definition.

Note the second `{ }` to keep `\@tempa` local. I assume here that `\special` doesn't mind the group

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I tried the first suggestion. It says #1 is not defined. I have \defcolor{red}... before this command and I can use \red in the text. So why is \red (or #1) remaining undefined inside the macro? In the second suggestion, there is a missing closing }. After inserting an additional } it still does not work.

Comment: Could it be that you define `\red` inside a group? You might want to change `\def` to `\gdef` inside `\defcolor` to make color definitions global by default or use `\global\defcolor{red}{...}`, at least for testing.

Comment: @mahes25: It works fine in my tests. Please see the grouping issue in my last comment and if this doesn't fix it, post a minimal example which shows the error.

Comment: You are right! I used the \gdef and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I see a harmless `\noexpand` by `\special`, but `\special` isn't expandable.

Answer (score 3):

try it this way

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\defcolor#1#2{\@namedef{#1}{#2}}%
\def\colortext#1#2{\special{ts: text fillcolor \@nameuse{#1}}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\defcolor{red}{1.0,0.0,0.0}

\colortext{red}{sometext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is helpful. I did not know about \@namedef and \@nameuse.

Comment: @mahes25: Also the `etoolbox` package gives you `\csdef` and `\csuse` which don't require `\makeatletter`. The `\@namedef` and `\csdef` macros can be prefixed with `\global` to make the definitions global.

Comment: I just want to confirm if you actually tested your solution.